# istanbuljs / nyc test coverage report validation along with individual files with different configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

I am writing unit-test cases using mocha, istanbul & nyc.

I am trying to check the coverage report should be 80% overall in `.nycrc.json`.

```
{
  "statements": 80,
  "branches": 80,
  "functions": 80,
  "lines": 80
}
```

If the consolated report is not covered 80% then throw an error in the terminal.

Now, my question: is there any way to check individual files coverage reports?

For example:

I am trying to configure the `.nycrc.json` in such a way that, individual files should be covered 65% at least and the overall report should be covered 80%.

As the consolated report doesn't pass the 80% then it automatically throws an error in the terminal. In a similar way if the individual file doesn't cover the 65% coverage then it should throw an error like "Single file don't cover in the file: file_name".

So, in `.nycrc.json` there are two configurations like:

```
// consolated coverage validation
{
  "statements": 80,
  "branches": 80,
  "functions": 80,
  "lines": 80
}
// individual files coverage validation with some another config
{
  "statements": 65,
  "branches": 65,
  "functions": 65,
  "lines": 65
}
```

This is my `.nycrc.json` file:

```
{
    "cache": false,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "extension": [".js"],
    "include": ["src/**/*.js"],
    "exclude": ["src/**/*.test.js"],
    "reporter": [
        "lcov",
        "text",
        "text-summary",
        "cobertura"
    ],
    "report-dir": "unittest_report",
    "statements": 80,
    "branches": 80,
    "functions": 80,
    "lines": 80,
    "watermarks": {
        "statements": [70, 90],
        "branches": [70, 90],
        "functions": [70, 90],
        "lines": [70, 90]
    }
}
```

I am trying to add this validation, to check if someone adds a new unit-test file then its coverage report should check in run time. I am trying to add such type of configuration.

I didn't see such configuration here: [istanbuljs/nyc](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#configuration-files)

---

### Git Hub Issue:

[istanbuljs / nyc test coverage report validation along with individual files with different configuration](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1491)

Comment: Raised git ticket: https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1491